# Script working but throwing 'The syntax of the command is incorrect.' error

Tags: windows, batch

I am trying to use this script here: http://www.logaans-site.co.uk/2009/10/17/simpler-version-of-the-7-zip-backup/, it works but is throwing a "The syntax of the command is incorrect.   " message. Can someone please tell me why ?

Thanks

```
@ECHO OFF

ECHO 7-Zip backup script
ECHO Written by Alex Boyne-Aitken
ECHO Last update: 07/11/2009
ECHO.

ECHO TRACE: Parse arguments: '%~f1'
IF EXIST %~f1 GOTO labelBegin

ECHO.
ECHO ERROR: Settings file not found!
GOTO labelWaitEnd

:labelBegin

ECHO.
ECHO TRACE: Reading settings
FOR /F "eol=# tokens=1,2 delims==" %%i IN (%~f1) DO (
SET %%i=%%j
ECHO TRACE: %%i = '%%j'
)

SET varTimeStamp=%DATE:~-4%-%DATE:~3,2%-%DATE:~0,2%-%TIME:~0,2%-%TIME:~3,2%
SET varTargetBackupSet=%varBackupPath%\%varTimeStamp%-backup.zip

ECHO.
ECHO TRACE: Backup set: '%varTargetBackupSet%'
ECHO TRACE: Command line: '"%varPathToSevenZip%\7z" a -t%varArchiveType% "%varTargetBackupSet%" @"%varInclusionsFile%" -xr@"%varExclusionsFile%"'

ECHO.
ECHO TRACE: Executing backup
"%varPathToSevenZip%\7z" a -t%varArchiveType% "%varTargetBackupSet%" @"%varInclusionsFile%" -xr@"%varExclusionsFile%"

IF /I NOT "%varWaitAtEnd%" == "true" GOTO labelEnd

:labelWaitEnd
PAUSE
:labelEnd
```

The error is thrown around this line:

```
FOR /F "eol=# tokens=1,2 delims==" %%i IN (%~f1) DO (
SET %%i=%%j
ECHO TRACE: %%i = '%%j'
)
```

Comment: That part of the code is reading the settings. Have you verified the information in "settings.txt" is correct?